# how can i group specific rows

Tags: gridview, extjs

I have a grid with rows that can have same value in `NumRow` field

example : 4 records with the same field :

```
NumRow = 1234
```

I want to group them all and apply specific style.

And if I can brings them grouped after sorting on other fields.

infos : I am using

1. RowSelectionModel : `singleSelect :true`
2. `Ext.data.GroupingStore1`.
3. `Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel`

> The GridView  :

```
var gridView = new Ext.grid.GridView({
            showPreview: false, 
            enableRowBody: true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using GroupingView with a GroupStore?

- http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.GroupingView